# itterows updating issues for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I have a dataset:

```
    id   name  m
0   1    mina  0
1   1    sara  0
2   2    travi 0
3   3    caty  0
5   4    el    0
6   6    tom   0
```

I wrote the following code for changing my dataframe

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     if(row['m']==0):
          df.loc[df['id'] ==row['id'] ,'m'] = 1
      print(row['name'])
```

and the result is

```
  mina
  sara
  travi
  caty
  el
  tom
```

my question is why the second row is printed? 
Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: the code you wrote for changing the dataframe sets column m to 1 for every row that has an id that matches the id of your row.... nothing should be deleted, it's just an inefficient way of setting everything to m=1

Comment: what are you expecting the code to do?

Comment: What do you mean "the second row is repeated"? I don't see any repeated rows.

Comment: I think the second row shouldn't be printed.@Stael @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you need?

```
for item in df['id']:
      if ((df.loc[df['id'] == item, 'm'].values[0]) == 0):
            df.loc[df['id'] == item, 'm'] = 1  
       print(item)
```

Comment: exactly. So, itterrows cannt do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Check pandas documentation 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

It says:

> You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not
>   guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the
>   iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no
>   effect.

There is why it happens.
Use something like this: `print('\n'.join(df.drop_duplicates(subset='id')[name]))`

Comment: My problem is not the printing . I think the second row should be printed. My problem is not duplicate removing